# Set JQuery page reload when at specify screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi is there a way to set a function in jQuery to active only when screen size is more than 713px than active this function like CSS @media screen and (min-width:713px){} . I wanted in JQuery to active when screen more than 713px.

```
jQuery(window).resize(function(){location.reload();});
```

Thanks

Comment: in the resize function add -- (var width = $(window).width(); if (width > 713) { location.reload(); })

Comment: @Tasos thank you so much!! it works!!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the condition in your function:

```
jQuery(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width > 713) location.reload();
});
```